# No Output on Running Gulp SASS

Tags: gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

Gulp Version 3.9.1

Gulp Ruby SASS Version 2.1.0

Function:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    sass('C:/xampp/htdocs/bptc/vendor/bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss', 
        {   trace: true,
            verbose: true
        })
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/vendor'))
});
```

Output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\bptc>gulp sass
[12:00:40] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\bptc\gulpfile.js
[12:00:40] Starting 'sass'...
[12:00:40] Running command sass --sourcemap=none --trace --update C:/xampp/htdocs/bptc/vendor/bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss:C:\Users\agf365.BH\AppData\Local\Temp\gulp-ruby-sass\84a250b0f5e0b41f769aa0a7c55878cc\font-awesome.css
[12:00:40] Finished 'sass' after 41 ms
```

No error messages is appearing yet there are no output files.

Comment: Have you tried running the command that is logged manually? Does it work?

Comment: Did you check `C:\Users\agf365.BH\AppData\Local\Temp\gulp-ruby-sass\84a250b0f5e0b41f769aa0a7c55878cc\font-awesome.css`?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung How can I do that?

Comment: @Neal I checked but couldn't even find the folder as it didn't exist or might have been deleted after the process was completed.

Comment: I switch from gulp-ruby-sass to gulp-sass and now it's working fine.